# Adding Characters to each object in Array

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I have an array of characters:

```
'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
```

That I need to transform into:

```
'(1)','(2)','(3)','(4)','(5)','(6)','(7)','(8)','(9)'
```

I recall there is a function to do so in coffeescript but cannot locate where or how it was defined.

How can I efficiently append opening and closing parenthesis to each object in the array?

Comment: Use simple loop or map function for functional programming look.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, especially with this wierd syntax to define arrays. Are you truing to add `'('` and `')'` character to the beginning and to the end of each string in an array?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Yes,

Comment: Don't forget you can express your array as `1..9`, assuming that's your actual code.

Comment: @Cheezmeister I'm sorry, it's not, I just used that for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as **Alexander Ravikovich** mentioned in comments, you could do it using either a [loop](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
arr = ['1', '2', '3']

new_arr = ("(#{s})" for s in arr)
# => [ '(1)', '(2)', '(3)' ]
```

or an [`Array::map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
new_arr = arr.map (s) -> "(#{s})"
# => [ '(1)', '(2)', '(3)' ]
```

Note that I used [CS string Interpolation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) to simplify my code.

Comment: Where can I test this in the browser? Like js fiddle but for coffeescript

Comment: By the way, [jsfiddle supports coffeescript](https://jsfiddle.net/L2uhemsm/) as well.